# MYSQL SQL SYNTAX ERROR

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

FIRST OF ALL THE AUTHOR SAID THAT:
If you get SQL errors it should be because its made to work with databases that accept ADD IF NOT EXISTS, if yours dont do that you need to init the tables yourself and comment out the init query.

I'm trying to put that on my Phpmyadmin on the SQL zone:

```
ALTER TABLE vrp_user_vehicles ADD IF NOT EXISTS vehicle_colorsecondary varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;
```

> ALTER TABLE vrp_user_vehicles ADD IF NOT EXISTS vehicle_colorsecondary varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;
>
> MySQL ha dicho: Documentación  #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su
>   sintax cerca 'IF NOT EXISTS vehicle_colorsecondary varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;' en la
>   linea 1

This is all I need: https://pastebin.com/ZwDc8pGG

Comment: Can you edit and post this in English?

Comment: Please fix you tags. PHP is not phpmyadmin. mysql is not sql-server.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax for checking wheter a column is exists for adding it is:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'vrp_user_vehicles' AND 
COLUMN_NAME = 'veh_type')
BEGIN

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[vrp_user_vehicles] ADD 
    [veh_type] varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

 EXEC sp_executesql
    N'UPDATE [dbo].[vrp_user_vehicles] SET [veh_type] = 1            WHERE [Ref] IS NOT NULL'

END
```

Comment: How can I do all that into all that commands? https://pastebin.com/ZwDc8pGG

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE  `vrp_user_vehicles` ADD IF NOT EXISTS `veh_type` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  'default'

Please try this.

Comment: I need to check if not exists every time I start my script with this commands https://pastebin.com/ZwDc8pGG